# Printing string array also prints null

Tags: java, arrays, string, printing, null

When I am printing contents of a string array the output is printing 'null' as well. I am not sure what's wrong with this. Here is the output, what I expect is the output without 'null'

```
null(wa?>=0)nullnull*(wo?>=0)nullnull*(4*wa?+7*wo?>=50)nullnull*(d1=10)nullnull*((d2=1)+(k=2))nullnull
```

Thanks and appreciate your help. I would say my skill in Java in beginner level and I started two weeks back.

Here is the actual code:

```
        String[] arrStr = new String[50];
        int countStr = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < para.length; i++) {
            if (para[i] == '(') {
                count = count + 1;
            }
            if (para[i] == ')') {
                count = count - 1;
            }
            if (count > 0) {
                arrStr[countStr] = arrStr[countStr] + para[i];
            } else {
                if (para[i] == ')') {
                    arrStr[countStr] = arrStr[countStr] + para[i];
                    countStr += 1;
                } else {
                    countStr += 1;
                    arrStr[countStr] = arrStr[countStr] + para[i];
                    // System.out.println(para[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(countStr);

        for (int i = 0; i < countStr; i++) {
            System.out.print(arrStr[i]);
        }
```

Before this part, I am reading the following string from a word document:

```
(wa?>=0)AND(wo?>=0)AND(4*wa?+7*wo?>=50)AND(d1=10)AND((d2=1)+(k=2))
```

I think the problem may be due to the line:

```
arrStr[countStr] = arrStr[countStr] + para[i];
```

Since `arrStr[countStr]` is null initially and I add an element to it, it saves it as `null+para[i]`. Do you think it is possible?

Like when I try: `System.out.println(arrStr[0]);` I get the output as

```
null(wa?>=0)
```

Comment: If you need help debugging your code, the actual code would help.

Comment: Can you please show the code that's causing the error?

Comment: After every assignment opeartion done on the array, print out the value that you have assigned. It will give you a better picture of where the value is being set as null. If you can provide th entire code, it would be easier to point out where the problem is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
System.out.println(null + "Bla");
```

prints `nullBla`. A null represented as String is "null". The issue here is that initially all your String[] is made of null. You need to initialize them first. Typically,

```
Arrays.fill(arrStr, "");
```

Should do.

Comment: Thanks that's what I thought. Really appreciate all of you for taking your time to answer :)

Answer (score 0):

If any element in `arrStr` is null while printing, it will print that faithfully.

Without knowing specifics in your code, you can either ensure that no element in your array becomes null (ensure that the lengths match up and you're not skipping element in `arrStr`, or check for `null` before printing the element.

Answer (score 0):

You don't initialize the values of the `arrStr` array, you just allocate size for it, so each element of the array is null. When you assign a value to an element of the array, you concatenate its value (which is null) with the value of `para[i]`.

You should initialize your array before using it:

```
String[] arrStr = new String[50];
for (int i = 0; i < arrStr.length; i++) {
    arrStr[i] = "";
}
```

Comment: While this is an acceptable solution for this case, I hesitate to recommend this generally.  In my opinion, it is better to design code that handles the possibility of nulls than to design code that expects that there will be no nulls and hopes for the best.  The former should always end up being a more robust solution.